# How to use SQLContext and SparkContext inside foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use SparkContext and SQLContext inside `foreachPartition`, but unable to do it due to serialization error. I know that both objects are not serializable, but I thought that `foreachPartition` is executed on the master, where both Spark Context and SQLContext are available..

**Notation:**

```
`msg -> Map[String,String]`
`result -> Iterable[Seq[Row]]`
```

This is my current code (UtilsDM is an object that `extends Serializable`). The part of code that fails starts from `val schema =...`, where I want to write `result` to the `DataFrame` and then save it to Parquet. Maybe the way I organized the code is inefficient, then I'd like to here your recommendations. Thanks.

```
// Here I am creating df from parquet file on S3
val exists = FileSystem.get(new URI("s3n://" + bucketNameCode), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path("s3n://" + bucketNameCode + "/" + pathToSentMessages))
var df: DataFrame = null
if (exists) {
  df = sqlContext
    .read.parquet("s3n://bucket/pathToParquetFile")
}
UtilsDM.setDF(df)

// Here I process myDStream
myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition{iter =>
    val r = new RedisClient(UtilsDM.getHost, UtilsDM.getPort)
    val producer = UtilsDM.createProducer
    var df = UtilsDM.getDF
    val result = iter.map{ msg =>
        // ... 
        Seq(msg("key"),msg("value"))
    }

    // HERE I WANT TO WRITE result TO S3, BUT IT FAILS
    val schema = StructType(
                    StructField("key", StringType, true) ::
                    StructField("value", StringType, true)

    result.foreach { row =>
       val rdd = sc.makeRDD(row)
       val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

       // If the parquet file is not created, then create it
       var df_final: DataFrame = null
       if (df != null) {
          df_final = df.unionAll(df2)
       } else {
          df_final = df2
       }
       df_final.write.parquet("s3n://bucket/pathToSentMessages)
}
  }
})
```

EDIT:

I am using Spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10.6.

Comment: which version of spark are you using ?

Comment: @MRSrinivas: I am using Spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10.6. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible. `SparkContext`, `SQLContext` and `SparkSession` can be used only on the driver. You can use sqlContext in the top level of `foreachRDD`:

```
 myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
     val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
     ... 
 })
```

You cannot use it in transformation / action:

```
myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
     rdd.foreach { 
        val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(...)
        ... 
     }
 })
```

You probably want equivalent of:

```
myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
   val foo = rdd.mapPartitions(iter => doSomethingWithRedisClient(iter))
   val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(foo, schema)
   df.write.parquet("s3n://bucket/pathToSentMessages)
})
```

Comment: Ok,thanks. It means that instead of `foreachPartition` I should use `mapPartitions` to return `result`? Could you please show how to do it?

Comment: Should it be like this? It does not compile for me: `myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => { val finalResult = rdd.mapPartitions(iter =>
        val r = new RedisClient(UtilsDM.getHost, UtilsDM.getPort)  val result = iter.map{ msg =>  ...  })  ) })`

Comment: I don't fully comprehend your code but whatever you do you cannot use sqlContext inside `RDD.foreach` , `RDD.map` , `RDD.mapPartitions` etc.

Comment: I mean this part does not compile: `(iter => doSomethingWithRedisClient(iter))` Coule you please show it for me concrete example? Thanks.

Comment: It compiles now. One more question. Can serializable object like in my case `UtilsDM` be used in the cluster? Or will this solution only work locally?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that using an existing SparkContext (assume I have created a sparkContext sc beforehand) inside a loop works i.e.

```
// this works
stream.foreachRDD( _ => {
    // update rdd
    .... = SparkContext.getOrCreate().parallelize(...)
})

// this doesn't work - throws a SparkContext not serializable error
stream.foreachRDD( _ => {
    // update rdd
    .... = sc.parallelize(...)
})
```

Comment: Did you understand what the op wanted to achieve?