# How to convert JavaDStream into RDD ? OR Is there a way i can create new RDD inside map function of JavaDStream?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

The streaming data which i am getting from kafka is the path of hdfs file and i need to get the data of that file .

```
batchInputDStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, FreshBatchInput>() {

            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> arg0)
                    throws Exception {
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(arg0._2);
                 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FreshBatchInput.class);  

                    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
                    FreshBatchInput input = (FreshBatchInput)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);


                return input.getPath();    
            }
        });
```

here input.getPath() is the hdfs path of file .

There is no option to collect JavaDstream Object otherwise i would have used that by first collecting data and than getting data from file.

Iam not able to create new RDD inside map function it is giving error Task Not Serializable.

Is there any other option ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreachRDD. It is executed on driver, so rdd actions are allowed

```
transformed.foreachRDD (rdd -> {
    String inputPath = doSomethingWithRDD(rdd)
    rdd.sparkContext.textFile(inputPath) ...
});
```

Remember that you cannot create RDD inside transformations or actions - RDDs can be created only on the driver. Similar question with example of foreachRDD is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691086/how-to-use-sqlcontext-and-sparkcontext-inside-foreachpartition). This means, you cannot use SparkContext inside map, filter or foreachPartition

Comment: But i will face same issue with this solution also because i wont be able to call sparcontext.readFile inside call method ?

Comment: @NidhiShah I've deleted text about transform as it could be wrong - foreachRDD should be ok for you