# dataframe map and hivecontext issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Env: Spark 1.6 and Scala

Hi,

I have dataframe DF and tried to run

```
val configTable= hivecontext.table("mydb.myTable")

configTable.rdd.map(row=>{
    val abc =hivecontext.sql("select count(*) as num_rows from mydb2.mytable2")
}).collect()
```

I am getting exception

```
17/03/28 22:47:04 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is it not allowed to use SparkSQL in `rdd.map`? Any work around for this?
  Thanks

Comment: could you provide a full stack-trace of your error as well as (at least part of) the code you use to initialize `HiveContext`.

Comment: overall, this should explain why it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691086/how-to-use-sqlcontext-and-sparkcontext-inside-foreachpartition

Comment: however, at least in Spark 2.0, HiveContext (as well as SQLContext) is serializable, so the problem might be either specific to HiveContext implementation or something in your initialization code

Comment: What is output for configTable.show() ?