# NullPointerException: creating dataset/dataframe inside foreachPartition/foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, apache-spark-sql

1) If I use the following one in both local and cluster mode, I get `NullPointerException` error

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
val testDS = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
  Seq(
    ABC("1","2", 1),
    ABC("3","9", 3),
    ABC("8","2", 2),
    ABC("1","2", 3),
    ABC("3","9", 1),
    ABC("2","7", 1),
    ABC("1","3", 2))
).as[ABC]

val t = testDS
  .rdd
  .groupBy(_.c)
  .foreachPartition(
    p => p.foreach(
      a => {
        val id = a._1
        println("inside foreach, id: " + id)
        val itABC = a._2

        val itSeq = itABC.toSeq
        println(itSeq.size)

        val itDS = itSeq.toDS // Get "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" here
        itDS.show()

        funcA(itDS, id)
      }
    )
  )
println(t.toString)
```

Or

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
val testDS = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
  Seq(
    ABC("1","2", 1),
    ABC("3","9", 3),
    ABC("8","2", 2),
    ABC("1","2", 3),
    ABC("3","9", 1),
    ABC("2","7", 1),
    ABC("1","3", 2))
).as[ABC]

testDS
  .rdd
  .groupBy(_.c)
  .foreachPartition(
    p => p.foreach(
      a => {
        val id = a._1
        println("inside foreach, id: " + id)
        val itABC = a._2

        import sparkSession.implicits._
        val itDS = sparkSession.createDataFrame( 
          sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(itABC.toList, numSlices=200)) // get "NullPointerException" here
        itDS.show()

        funcA(itDS, id)
      }
    )
  )
```

Here's the output log for 1):

```
    17/10/26 15:07:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 4]17/10/26 15:07:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8, 10.142.17.137, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SL.scala:176)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SL.scala:167)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1.apply(SL.scala:166)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1.apply(SL.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/10/26 15:07:29 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 12, 10.142.17.137, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SL.scala:176)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SL.scala:167)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1.apply(SL.scala:166)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1.apply(SL.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:924)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL.generateScaleGraphs(SL.scala:165)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.GA$$anonfun$generateGraphsDataScale$1.apply(GA.scala:23)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.GA$$anonfun$generateGraphsDataScale$1.apply(GA.scala:21)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.GA$.generateGraphsDataScale(GA.scala:21)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.GA$.main(GA.scala:52)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.GA.main(GA.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SL.scala:176)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SL.scala:167)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1.apply(SL.scala:166)
    at com.a.data_pipeline.SL$$anonfun$generateScaleGraphs$1.apply(SL.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

2) But if I use the following code, running in local mode works fine, but running in cluster mode I get `NullPointerException` or `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration`

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
val testDS = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
  Seq(
    ABC("1","2", 1),
    ABC("3","9", 3),
    ABC("8","2", 2),
    ABC("1","2", 3),
    ABC("3","9", 1),
    ABC("2","7", 1),
    ABC("1","3", 2))
).as[ABC]

val test = testDS
  .rdd
  .groupBy(_.c)
  .foreachPartition(
    p => p.foreach(
      a => {
        val id = a._1
        println("inside foreach, id: " + id)
        val itABC = a._2
        val ss = SparkSessionUtil.getInstance(clusterMode)
        import ss.implicits._
        val itDS = ss.createDataFrame(
        ss.sparkContext.parallelize(itABC.toList, numSlices=200)).as[ABC]
        itDS.show()
        funcA(itDS, id)  // in funcA, I'd like to use this itDS(Dataset) to do some calculation, like itDS.groupby().agg().filter()
      }
    )
  )
```

Here's the system out log for 2):

```
17/10/26 14:19:12 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
inside foreach, id: 1
17/10/26 14:19:13 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  3|  9|  1|
|  2|  7|  1|
+---+---+---+

inside foreach, id: 2
17/10/26 14:19:14 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
17/10/26 14:19:14 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  8|  2|  2|
|  1|  3|  2|
+---+---+---+

inside foreach, id: 3
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  3|  9|  3|
|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

I would like to use `id related Dataset(itDS)` in `funcA(itDS, id)` to calculate something like `itDS.groupby().agg().filter()`,How should I solve this problem? Thank you in advance?

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace associated to the `NullPointerException`? Out of curiosity, what happens if you remove the `as[ABC]` from the innermost `foreach` of the first code snippet?

Comment: Thank you, @AlexandreDupriez ! I updated the stack trace, in the meantime, I removed the `as[ABC]` as you mentioned, but `NullPointerException ` error still happen

Comment: You don't need go through such complexity. All you are doing is separating the original dataset to multiple datasets on common third column and finally you want to apply funcA on all the separate datasets, isn't that so? If you specify the exact requirements of funcA then we can help you better by not going through such complexity. :)

Comment: Hi @RameshMaharjan the inputs of funcA() are `itDS: Dataset[ABC]` and `id: Int`; funcA() is processing the data in itDS and saving the outputs to datastores. It's wired that seems we can not create dataset/dataframe inside foreachPartition/foreach, I don't why we can not do that.

Comment: I could see the input arguments of funcA from the question code. I wanted to see the logics inside funcA so that i can help you writing it in different way.

Comment: This kind of nested DataSet processing is a no go, and why on earth would you even want to? Just pass the `seq[ABC]` to your `funcA`(_without_ transforming it to a `DataSet`)  - you can do `groupBy` and `filter` on `Seq` so just do that. `DataSets` are for _distributed_ processing of BIG datasets...

Comment: Thank you, @RameshMaharjan and @GlennieHellesSindholt ! funcA() relys heavily on dataset/dataframe, I'm using `sparkSession.sql()`, lots of sql and complex algorithms in that function are pipelined, it's not that easy to rewrite code by using Seq[ABC] only. So it's impossible to create dataset/dataframe inside foreachPartition/foreach, right? Or Spark 2.2.0 still haven't supported this feature?

Comment: @faustineinsun In this case, why don't you apply `funcA` on your original `Dataset`, after the `groupBy`? Have you considered using a `udf` to wrap `funcA`, and then apply it on the columns of the dataset which the function operates on? Otherwise, as previous comments suggest, I do not think converting the sequence of rows to a dataset from within the `foreachPartitions` is the right way to go (should it even works).

Comment: Thank you, @AlexandreDupriez ! The problem has been solved by restructuring the codes from `sparkSession.sql()` to `Seq[ABC]` so that sparkSession isn't referenced in the map/foreach function closure, since sparkSession isn't serializable, it's designed to run on the driver not on workers.

Answer (score 4):

Recently encountered the same issue and since there was no answer Trying to add answer this question....
 faustineinsun Comment is answer :

> Thank you, @AlexandreDupriez ! The problem has been solved by
>   restructuring the codes from sparkSession.sql() to Seq[ABC] so that
>   sparkSession isn't referenced in the map/foreach function closure,
>   since sparkSession isn't serializable, it's designed to run on the
>   driver not on workers

Conclusion : 
With in `foreach` , `foreachPartition` or `map`, `mapPartitions` you CANT create a new dataframe with spark session .read or .sql inside it it will throw null pointer exception.

Also have a look at :

[How to use SQLContext and SparkContext inside foreachPartition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691086/how-to-use-sqlcontext-and-sparkcontext-inside-foreachpartition)