# How to parallelize operations on partitions of a dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe df =

```
+--------------------+
|                id|
+-------------------+
|113331567dc042f...|
|5ffbbd1adb4c413...|
|08c782a4ae854e8...|
|24cee418e04a461...|
|a65f47c2aecc455...|
|a74355ef35d442d...|
|86f1a9b7ffc843b...|
|25c8abd6895e445...|
|b89ce33788f4484...|
.....................
```

with million elements.
I want to repartition the dataframe into multiple partitions and pass each partition elelemts as list to database api call that returns spark dataset.

Something like this.

```
df2 = df.repartition(10)

df2.foreach-partition { partition =>
   val result = spark.read
                .format("custom.databse")
                .where(__key in partition.toList)
                .load
}
```

And at the end I would ike to do a Union of all the result datasets returned for each of the partition.

expected output will be final dataset of strings.

```
 +--------------------+
    |   customer names|
    +-------------------+
    |eddy              |
    |jaman             |
    |cally             |
    |sunny             |
    |adam              |
    .....................
```

Can anyone help me to convert it to real code in spark-scala

Comment: Does your `api.call` return a collection?

Comment: it returns a dataset. its a call to a database.

Comment: Is the returned dataset a Spark `Dataset`?  Or a Scala collection like an `Iterator` of tuples?

Comment: spark dataset ...

Comment: In that case, would you expect the 10 generated Datasets be union-ed into one?  I would suggest you edit your question to include a minimal sample dataset, a method signature of the api call and expected output.

Comment: yes. 10 generated Datasets should be union-ed into one at the end. modified questions a little. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in documentation it could be possible to something like this. You'll have to use `RDD` API and `SparkContext` so you could use [parallelize](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize%5BT%5D(seq:Seq%5BT%5D,numSlices:Int)(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD%5BT%5D) to partition your data into `n` partitions. After that you can call [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#foreachPartition(f:Iterator%5BT%5D=%3EUnit):Unit) which should already give you iterator on your data directly, no need to collect data.

Comment: The API call returns a DATASET , which cannot be handled within foreachPartition. This solution will not workout.

Comment: Did you conclude that just from documentation or you tried this out? I'm not saying I'm right, I just want to see if I misunderstood something in the documentation. I see that it's taking function over `Iterator[T]` like so `def foreachPartition(f: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Unit): Unit `. `T` in this case should be the type wrapped into RDD, right?

Comment: problem is OP mentioned he needs to use "spark.read" , and you cannot pass "spark" in f. otherwise your answer is correct and have mentioned you in my Answer as well :)

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691086/how-to-use-sqlcontext-and-sparkcontext-inside-foreachpartition

Comment: @Sanket9394 Oh, I see, thanks! At the time I was writing the answer his code didn't look like it does now, or maybe I just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually what you are asking is not really possible in Spark.

Your API call is a SparkContext dependent function ( i.e. spark.read ) , And one cannot use a SparkContext inside a partition function. In simpler words, you cannot pass **spark** object to executors. [For ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691086/how-to-use-sqlcontext-and-sparkcontext-inside-foreachpartition)

For even simpler imagination : think of of a Dataset having each row as Dataset. Is it even possible ? no.

---

In your case there can be 2 ways to solve this :

**Case 1 : One by One then Union**

- Convert the keys to list and Split them evenly
- FOr each split call spark.read api and keep Unioning .

```
//split into 10000 sized lists
val listOfListOfKeys : List[List[String]]= df.collect().grouped(10000).toList

//Bring Dataset for 1st 10000 keys (1st list)
var resultDf = spark.read.format("custom.databse")
              .where(__key in listOfListOfKeys.apply(0)).load

//drop the 1st item
listOfListOfKeys.drop(1)

//bring rest of them
for (listOfKeys <- listOfListOfKeys) {
    val tempDf = spark.read.format("custom.databse")
                 .where(__key in listOfKeys).load

    resultDf.union(tempDf);

}
```

There will scaling issues with this approah because of the collected data on the driver. But if you want to use the "spark.read" api, then this might be the only easy way.

**Case 2 : foreachPartition + Normal DB call which returns a iterator**

If you can find another way to get the data from your Db which returns a iterator or any single threaded spark independent object. Then you can achieve what you want exactly by applying what Filip has answered i.e. `df.repartition.rdd.foreachPartition(yourDbCallFuntion())`

Comment: thanks. How can I run each of the iteration doing spark.read call in async thread ?

Comment: that is a difficult task and against the spirit of Spark. Because each spark.read is a Spark Job itself. if you really want to do it have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842048/launching-apache-spark-sql-jobs-from-multi-threaded-driver

Comment: thanks @Sanket9394. One more question. What I am seeing is that the .load method is executed on driver node and uses single core only. I also tried setting spark.driver.cores=8 , but it does not have any effect. any suggestions ?

Comment: any spark.XYZ will not run on driver, rather it runs on executors. Increasing driver resouces won't affect. How did you conclude that load is running on driver ?

Comment: the cpu load is very high on the driver machine. I think I know the reason why . Its because of 
.where(__key in listOfKeys).load . listOfKeys is actually derived from a dataframe loaded from s3.  sparkSession.read.load(s3location).select("id").map(row=>row.getString(0)).collect.toList